# ¿Cómo quito advertencia "Warning: Prop `style` did not match" cuando importo componente Image en nextjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

A la hora de importar una imagen con el componente Image de nextjs me sale la siguiente advertencia:

> Warning: Prop `style` did not match. Server: "display: block; max-width: 100%; width: initial; height: initial; background: none;
> opacity: 1; border: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;
> --darkreader-inline-bgimage:none; --darkreader-inline-bgcolor: initial; --darkreader-inline-border-top: initial;
> --darkreader-inline-border-right: initial; --darkreader-inline-border-bottom: initial; --darkreader-inline-border-left: initial;" Client: "display:block;max-width:100%;width:initial;height:initial;background:none;opacity:1;border:0;margin:0;padding:0"
> at img
> at span
> at span
> at Image (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/image.js:50:20)
> at LoadableImpl (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/shared/lib/loadable.js:142:5)
> at a
> at LinkComponent (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/link.js:108:19)
> at div
> at header
> at div
> at Header
> at div
> at Layout (webpack-internal:///./components/Layout.js:15:23)
> at div
> at Home
> at MyApp (webpack-internal:///./pages/_app.js:18:24)
> at ErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@next/react-dev-overlay/dist/client.js:8:20742)
> at ReactDevOverlay (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@next/react-dev-overlay/dist/client.js:8:23635)
> at Container (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/index.js:111:5)
> at AppContainer (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/index.js:300:24)
> at Root (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/index.js:508:25)

Ya he intentado importando dinámicamente, agregando un archivo .babelrc y colocándole un loader al componente y nada.

```
"dependencies": {
  "babel-preset-next": "^1.4.0",
  "next": "12.3.0",
  "react": "18.2.0",
  "react-dom": "18.2.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^2.0.7",
  "eslint": "8.23.1",
  "eslint-config-next": "12.3.0"
}
```

Código:

```
    import Image from "next/image"
    import Link from "next/link";
    import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
    // const Images = dynamic(() => import('next/image'));
    
    import styles from "../styles/Header.module.css";
    
    const Header = () => {
    
      return (
        <div>
          <header className={styles.header}>
            <div className={`container ${styles.menuLogo}`}>
              <Link href="/">
                <a>
                  <Image
                    src="/blog-img.svg"
                    width={190}
                    height={120}
                    alt="logo"
                  />
                </a>
              </Link>
          </header>
        </div>
      );
    };
    
   export default Header;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error se debe a la extensión dark reader que inyecta código cuando se esta renderizando y por ello sale este error. Si se desactiva se quita el error.

No afecta la aplicación, solo sale el error porque estamos en modo desarrollo.

La explicación detalla de la solución está en [github](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/40648).